# Welcome/home page in Ruby on Rails - best practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My homepage (or welcome page) will consist of data from two models (lets call them authors and posts). I am new to rails and not sure what is the best way to accomplish this.

Should I create a new controller called welcome which gathers data from the authors and posts and then display them in the welcome index view? Or should I have a welcome view under the post model which also gets data from authors? Or any other way to accomplish this?

I understand how to do all this technically but just unsure what is the best practice method using the rails framework.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The question is, is your home page just a landing page or will it be a group of pages?  If it's just a landing page, you don't expect your users to hang around there for long except to go elsewhere.  If it's a group of pages, or similar to an existing group, you can add an action to the controller it's most like.

What I've done for my current project is make a controller named `Static`, because I need 3 static pages.  The home page is one of these, because there isn't anything to see or do except go elsewhere.

To map a default route, use the following in `routes.rb`:

```
# Place at the end of the routing!
map.root :controller => 'MyController', :action => :index
```

In my case this would be:

```
map.root :controller => 'static', :action => :index
```

If you wish to, you could create a controller just for this home page.  I'd call it main, or something that you can remember which relates to the home page.  From there you can get your data and your models and defer to the output view.

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Posts.find(:all, :limit => 10, :order => 'date_posted', :include => :user)
  end
end
```

Assuming you have your model relationships defined correctly, the template to match it will be very simple.

Good luck, hope this helps.

Comment: So writing `@posts = Posts.find( ...` or `@posts = Posts.all` or something similar in this new controller/action wouldn't be considered violating the principles of DRY, even though such code may already appear in the `Post` controller's `index` action? Is there a better (more modular) way, which uses the already written code the `Post` controller's `index` action?

Answer (score 139):

There doesn't seem to be a single best practice.

**(1)** The standard `config/routes.rb` file seems to suggest that the root page (or home/welcome page) should be handled by `welcome#index`. If you were to be guided by that, then to generate the corresponding `welcome#index` controller/action, you can use the following command:

```
rails generate controller Welcome index
```

Then, in `config/routes.rb`, you can remove the GET route (`get "welcome/index"`) automatically added by the generator, and place the root route `root 'welcome#index'` (or `root :to => 'welcome#index'` in Rails `< 4`) at the top of the file, because it will probably be your most popular route and should be matched first.

Also remember to delete `public/index.html` in Rails `< 4`.

**(2)** The [official Ruby on Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root) uses `PagesController`. It actually suggests `pages#main`, though to me it makes more sense to go with `pages#home` (because "homepage" is the ubiquitous term/concept). Additionally, this controller can handle other *page-oriented* actions such as `pages#about`, `pages#contact`, `pages#terms`, `pages#privacy`, etc.

```
rails generate controller Pages home
```

And in `config/routes.rb`:

```
root 'pages#home'
```

**(3)** The [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#sec-static_pages), goes with `static_pages#home` and `static_pages#help`, etc., though I don't like the idea of denoting this controller with "static". These pages will still likely have some dynamic aspects to them, particularly the homepage!

**(4)** Though it does not discuss how to handle a *homepage*, [RailsCast #117 on Semi-Static Pages](http://railscasts.com/episodes/117-semi-static-pages) suggests yet another set of approaches to *show*-only resources.

I feel preference toward 1 and/or 2. With the "and" scenario, you could use welcome#index and pages#about, etc., whereas with the "or" scenario, you could use pages#home, pages#about, etc. If forced to choose, *I would go with option 2* just because you end up with less code. And btw, 2 and 3 are pretty much the same, apart from the word "static".

Answer (score 29):

I asked myself something like this when I first started Rails. Here's what you need to know:

- Models are not necessarily directly related to controllers and views.

That is, a particular controller/view combination can work with as many models as you need to generate that particular page.

The purpose of the controller is to prepare the dataset you need to display, irrespective of what models are used to store that data.

The purpose of the view is to then display that data in the most appropriate way.

In other words, controller/view combinations are never 'under' a particular model. They use models, but are not under them in any hierarchical relationship. In fact, they are **peers** to whatever models they use.

I think the confusion comes from the scaffold generator example found in AWDR and other introductory texts, like:

ruby script/generate scaffold model controller

I know that this implied relationship between model and controller/views confused me for a bit. But there is no strict relationship, really. If there were, then it would be very difficult to do anything complicated with the MVC approach. And clearly, that is not the case.

Hope this helps.

-- John

Comment: What is your answer to the question?

Comment: Rather than competing with other answers (which are more _directly_ related to the _presenting problem_ the questioner has), this is related to a _misconception_ that John perceives the questioner to have.  This is useful.  There is no reason for John to repeat what others have said in order to address an aspect of the question which they did not address.

Answer (score 11):

The best practice would be your first suggestion. Create a 'welcome' controller and call the records from whichever models you want. Have a root route point to that controller. Very clean and proper.

Answer (score 9):

Please note that in Rails3, correct way to handle this is to add following line to the end of the routes.rb file:

```
root :to => "welcome#index"
```

and delete public/index.html.erb.

Please also note that welcome#index corresponds to index action in a WelcomeController and the code from The Wicked Flea's answer would look like:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Posts.find(:all, :limit => 10, :order => 'date_posted', :include => :user)
  end
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't it either be "welcomes" controller or for a singular resource, use the show action.

Answer (score 9):

**This answer is as of Rails 3.2.1.**

First set up a Controller for pages, named for example `static`:

```
$ rails generate controller static
```

In file `app/controllers/static_controller.rb`:

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController
    def index       
    end
end
```

Create the new View file `app/views/index.html.erb`

And finally configure your `config/routes.rb`:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
   match 'home', :to => "static#index"
   root :to => "static#index"
end
```

This will make both `/home` and `/` go to whatever you put in the View file you just created.

Comment: Very nice solution! I'm being nitpicky, but I would suggest making the second line read `match 'home' => 'static#index'`

Answer (score 6):

Create a new controller named as appropriately as you can. SummaryController? StartController? DailyFrontPageController? You'll have an idea.

Not only that, I'd seriously consider creating a new Model, *not* ActiveRecord-based, that collects the information from your Author and Post models (or whatever their real names are) for presentation in your view. The alternative is to assemble the data in the controller, which will almost certainly be messy - it was every time I tried it, and I tried it a lot. A separate model seems to end up a lot tidier.

If the processing is relatively straightforward, why not try building the data in the controller first, then wrap the output in a Struct, then replace the Struct with a real class and move the construction there, refactoring all the way. It shouldn't add too much to the total time (most of the code can be reused) and you'll get a good idea of what works best for you.