# Static pages in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm wondering what the best way to do static pages in Rails is, or rather Rails 3. I've always been a little confused about this, like should I create a controller or not?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are a variety of approaches you can take (they're not all *good* approaches).

#### 1 - `public` directory

If it's truly static, you can put it in the `public` directory. Things in the `public` directory will be served immediately, without going through the Rails stack.

Advantages:

- Because it doesn't have to waste time going through the Rails stack, the client will receive a faster response.

Disadvantages:

- You won't be able to use your sites layout. Or view helpers like [`link_to`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to?q=link_to).
- Instead of your views being in one place (`app/views`), now they're in two places (`app/views` *and* `public`). This can be confusing.

Thoughts: I feel pretty strongly that the disadvantages outweigh the advantages here. If you're looking to make a minor improvement in speed at the expense of readability and programmer happiness, why use Rails in the first place?

#### 2 - Place in `app/views` and render directly from the Router

It is [*possible*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24982111/can-i-render-a-layout-directly-from-routes-rb-without-a-controller) to render views from the router. However, it definitely isn't The Rails Way.

From the official [RailsGuide on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html):

> ## 1 The Purpose of the Rails Router
>
> The Rails router recognizes URLs and dispatches them to a controller's action.

Architecturally, there isn't anything inherently wrong with having a router map directly to a view. Many other frameworks do just that. However, Rails does not do that, and deviating from an established convention is likely to confuse other developers.

---

> like should I create a controller or not?

Unless you want to take one of the approaches mentioned above - yes, you should create a controller.

The question then becomes what to name the controller. This answer outlines some options. I'll list them here with some thoughts. I'll also add three other options.

---

#### 3 - Use `ApplicationController`

```
# routes.rb
get "/about" to: "application#about"

# application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def about
    render "/about"
  end
end

# app/views/about.html.erb
```

The advantage here is that you don't introduce overhead/bloat by creating a new controller and folder. The disadvantage is that it's not The Rails Way. Every controller you create inherits from `ApplicationController`. `ApplicationController` is typically used to house functionality that you want to share between all other controllers. See this example from the [Action Controller Overview Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :require_login
 
  private
 
  def require_login
    unless logged_in?
      flash[:error] = "You must be logged in to access this section"
      redirect_to new_login_url # halts request cycle
    end
  end
end
```

#### 4 - `StaticController` or `StaticPagesController`

Michael Hartl's popular Ruby on Rails Tutorial [uses](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#sec-generated_static_pages) a `StaticPagesController`. I agree with the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11003820/1927876) I got this from in that I don't like this approach because the pages often aren't actually static.

Also, there is a possibility of confusion - why did we put other static views in separate controllers? Shouldn't static views be rendered from the `StaticPagesController`? I don't think the possibility of confusion is too high, but still wanted to note it.

Also note Hartl's [footnote](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#cha-3_footnote-6):

> Our method for making static pages is probably the simplest, but it’s not the only way. The optimal method really depends on your needs; if you expect a large number of static pages, using a Static Pages controller can get quite cumbersome, but in our sample app we’ll only need a few. If you do need a lot of static pages, take a look at the high_voltage gem. ↑

#### 5 - `PagesController`

The official Ruby on Rails [routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root) uses `PagesController`. I think this approach is fine, but it isn't descriptive at all. Everything is a page. What distinguishes these pages from the other pages?

#### 6 - `UncategorizedPagesController`

I would call the controller `UncategorizedPagesController`, because that's exactly what they are - uncategorized pages. Yes, it's a little more cumbersome to type and read. I prefer the advantage of clarity over conciseness, but I could understand the choice to be more concise and go with `PagesController`, or something else.

#### 7 - High Voltage gem

With [High Voltage](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage), you don't have to do the tedious work of writing out routes and empty controller actions:

```
# routes.rb
root 'pages#home'
get '/about', to: 'pages#about'
get '/contact', to: 'pages#contact'
get '/help', to: 'pages#help'
get '/terms-of-service', to: 'pages#terms_of_service'
get '/landing-page', to: 'pages#landing_page'
...

# pages_controller.rb

def PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def about
  end

  def contact
  end

  def help
  end

  def terms_of_service
  end

  def landing_page
  end

  ...
end
```

You just add your pages to `app/views/pages` and link to them: `<%= link_to 'About', page_path('about') %>`.

Comment: Wow this is a great answer! updated this to the best answer.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the compliment :)

Answer (score 15):

It depends on if they're truly static.  You can always add pages to the `public/` directory of your app, and they'll work just fine.  They don't even fire up rails or touch the routing engine.

However, most pages on the site, including static, still need to use the site's layout.  You don't want to have to update the layout in dozens of pages separately.  In this case, you can create a "catchall" controller.  Here's an example:

```
rails g controller site home about_us location
```

Then you can put the page-specific content in `app/views/site/home.html.erb`, for instance.

**UPDATE**: You can go a step further and cache those pages with a call to `caches_page` near the top of your controller:

```
class SiteController < ApplicationController
  caches_page :home, :about_us, :location
end
```

Just be aware that if you have dynamic page elements, like a list of links that changes based on whether the user is logged in, page caching isn't going to work for you.  But this info should get you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

If they're 100% static, just shove them into public.
For example, when you spin up a new rails project, there's an `index.html` in your public.

If you want nicer routing, then yeah, creating a controller probably wouldn't be a bad idea.

Comment: We'll I'd like to take advantage of ERB I think, so I can keep my layouts etc.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to create a controller. Good tutorial and explanation on static pages:
http://railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#top

Comment: This link is no longer valid.