# Heroku - "This page does not exist" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deployment, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working through a Rails tutorial and am trying to deploy my demo app to Heroku, and not having much luck -- I get a "This page does not exist" error when I visit the page.  I can run the app just fine on the localhost server.  My logs are below...I'm a complete newbie at Rails, so any direction would be appreciated!

(If it matters, I'm runnings Rails 4 and using Ruby 2.0.0p353.)

```
2013-12-31T22:36:10.639947+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=aqueous-scrubland-1350.herokuapp.com fwd="66.108.171.204" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=8ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-12-31T22:36:09.524805+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=aqueous-scrubland-1350.herokuapp.com fwd="66.108.171.204" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=251ms status=404 bytes=1351
2013-12-31T23:40:59.592539+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2013-12-31T23:40:59.592983+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2013-12-31T23:41:03.038207+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-12-31T23:41:03.668269+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-12-31 23:41:03] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2013-12-31T23:41:03.668269+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2013-12-31T23:41:03.668269+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `start'
2013-12-31T23:41:03.668269+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2013-12-31T23:41:03.668269+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2013-12-31T23:41:03.668269+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2013-12-31T23:41:03.668269+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
2013-12-31T23:41:03.668269+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
2013-12-31T23:41:03.668269+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
2013-12-31T23:41:03.668516+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
2013-12-31T23:41:03.668516+00:00 app[web.1]:  bin/rails:4:in `require'
2013-12-31T23:41:03.668516+00:00 app[web.1]:  bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2013-12-31T23:41:03.668516+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-12-31 23:41:03] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2013-12-31T23:41:03.668516+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-12-31 23:41:03] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2013-12-31T23:41:03.668516+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2013-12-31T23:41:03.668269+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-12-31T23:41:05.125759+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
```

Comment: Have you created or migrated the database ?

Comment: Could you please post the whole log? The current log you have posted seems to indicate that your Dyno is idling due to a period of inactivity. Search for "sleeping" [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos).

Comment: Can you please post your `config.ru` and your `Procfile`?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you didn't specify a root path? Which tutorial are you using? If you are doing the first part of Hartl's tutorial the first chapter is supposed to show the error you are getting (since they haven't gone into routing etc. which probably happens in the next chapter) - http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue after pushing the changes to Heroku. As @derekyau pointed, it is because of the root page missing in heroku.

Add a default root page pointing to the welcome page, this solved my issue. For updating the welcome page follow the instructions here:

[Welcome/home page in Ruby on Rails - best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349743/welcome-home-page-in-ruby-on-rails-best-practice)